# Would "Garage Band" App be considered a genre?

Tags: genre-characteristics, songwriter, audio-software

My friend creates all of his music on an iPad using the 'Garage Band" App. His songs are so different from one another and would probably qualify for many different genre descriptions.  Would it be appropriate to use "Garage Band" as a musical genre?

Answer (score 1):

A musical genre is characterized by a particular style, form, or content, not by the means by which the music is produced. "Garage Band" is no more a genre than "studio recording" or "played by computer by Finale notation file" or "notated on paper" would be.

Answer (score 1):

No. First off, the term "Garage Band" is also associated with starting bands with low budges so having that as a genre would be confusing. Second is genre meant to show off what type of music the band/artist supplies.

There are many ways to group music like key, time signature, instrumentation which all show something, but trying to extend those to a genre would not make much sense.